# Application stops working is I use this=>url('router') in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, view-helpers, zend-framework-routing

The router is okay, it works via address bar
The router is okay if I echo the URL 
The app stops working if I echo $this->url('routename')

Guys, this is the router:

```
'ownedGoods' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/owned',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'index\index',
                        'action' => 'indexOwned'
                    )
                )
            ),
```

this is the invokable for controllers

```
'index\index' => 'AddGoods\Controller\IndexController',
```

Now when i open the URL: http://goodsApp.localhost:88/owned, **it works**

The trouble arised when I put along other links in navigation bar, where as other links like Add Goods and Home is working, but the owned is not.

```
 <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Home') ?></a></li>
 <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('add') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Add a good') ?></a></li>
 <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('owned') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('My Goods') ?></a></li>
```

App is not running, no controller and route is matched. Even not for home page, it shows

> Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException' with 
>   message 'Route with name "owned" not found' in
>   path\to\app\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack.php:313
>   Stack trace: #0
>   path\to\app\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Helper\Url.php(100):
>   Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack->assemble(Array, Array) #1
>   [internal function]: Zend\View\Helper\Url->__invoke('owned') #2 #2
>   path\to\app\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(400):
>   call_user_func_array(Object(Zend\View\Helper\Url), Array) #3
>   path\to\app\module\Application\view\layout\layout.phtml(48):
>   Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->__call('url', Array) #4
>   path\to\app\module\Application\view\layout\layout.phtml(48):
>   Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->url('owned') in
>   path\to\app\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack.php
>   on line 313

But, if I remove the nav bar link (the last li tag) from navigation, it again works. Even if instead of this->url('owned') I just echo 'owned' it still works.

The problem is only when I echo this->url('owned') in nav bar, it stops working and give the exception. It works if i use the route by address bar or by any other mean, like echoing 'owned' in nav bar.

Any more questions, ask me freely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your route name is **ownedGoods** Not **owned**

Comment: it works now. But why it was working before when I typed http://goodsApp.localhost:88/owned. And when I echo 'owned' in a tag? while it just not worked when I type echo this->url('owned'). The difference. Please.

Comment: owned is the last segment in your URL route. ownedGoods is the unique key of the route